# Find at least $k$ paths with reward at least $\gamma$

Tags: graphs

### The problem

Suppose we have a simple graph $G = (V,E)$, edge weights $c: E \to \mathbb{R}_+$ and node rewards $w: V \to \mathbb{R}$.

Given an integer $K$, positive scalar $B$ and a scalar $\gamma$, I would like to find a set of up to $K$ paths (either simple or not, whichever is easier to compute) such that the cost is less than the budget: 
$$\sum_{e \in \rho_k} c(e) \le B$$
and the rewards accumulated are at least $\gamma$: 
$$\sum_{v \in \rho_k} w(e) \ge \gamma$$
and if no path exists, return an empty set.

My question is three-fold:

1. This is NP-hard, right? If we could solve this problem, I think one could use it with a binary search to find the maximum weight path.
2. What assumptions on the graph would make this problem reasonable/easier to solve (hopefully more general than a tree)?
3. Is there a mixed integer approach (or something similar) to enumerate paths with these constraints?

### Some context

I want to solve this problem as a sub-routine for a submodular set cover algorithm, [FastCover](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/6540-fast-distributed-submodular-cover-public-private-data-summarization.pdf), where items in the set are paths in the graph $G$. This gives me a lot of lee-way about how to define $G$, which is why I am interested in particular types of graphs which will make this problem easier.

Comment: Do you want only simple paths, or arbitrary paths (might repeat vertices and/or edges)?

Comment: Either is fine, though I think I would prefer simple paths.  If the path repeats a vertex it _should_ only get reward once for that vertex.  Since I have a lot of leeway, I am more interested in whether there is a set of assumptions which makes this problem reasonable to solve rather than solving the problem for a particular set of assumptions.

Comment: OK.  At least for simple paths, it's NP-hard, as you suspected.  Even finding a single simple path is NP-hard: taking every edge weight and cost to be 1 and taking $B=\gamma=|V|-1$ yields the Hamiltonian path problem.  I don't know about non-simple paths but I'd guess it's probably NP-hard too.